# Recursion Question in Python. No Conditionals or Loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, math

I am trying to figure out how to print the word "hello" 121 times in python. I need to use a function without conditionals or loops, no new lines, and no multiplying the string by an integer.

I thinking something like:

```
print_hello(): 
   print('hello')
   print_hello()

print_hello()
```

but I can't seem to find a way to limit the recursive output without conditionals. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**
Here are all of the constraints to the challenge, it's possible recursion isn't the right approach.

- max 20 lines of code
- no inputs to a function.
- no imports or modules
- no if statements
- no loops (for or while)
- no new line characters (\n)
- can't do something like: print("hello\n"*121)
- no semi colons or tuples
- can't use exec functions

Comment: *"can't do something like: print("hello\n"*121)"* That's... unspecific.

Comment: Is `try ... except ...` allowed? Are `and` and `or` allowed? It's easy to fake a conditional in python using these operators.

Comment: @Stef I don't disagree. and it doesn't say those can't be used...

Comment: If you can't use `'\n'`, you can cheat and replace it with `'''` on one line and `'''` on the next line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Note: I've edited the message. So see better solution at the end)

If we don't try to find a silver bullet, using a trick that would have been forgotten in the restrictions (`global` variables to bypass parameters interdiction, `and`/`try` to bypass `if` interdiction, multiplying list to bypass multiplication of string interdiction, ...), as I understand the question, it is about finding a correct splitting in functions/subfunctions to have 20 lines of code (no semicolon)

For example, if we had to print 32 hello, we could, as geeks used to reason in power of 2,

```py
def h2():
    print("hello")
    print("hello")
def h4():
    h2()
    h2()
def h8():
    h4()
    h4()
def h16():
    h8()
    h8()
h16()
h16()
```

Which are 14 lines.
But the `def` parts complicates things, and complicates what is optimal. For example, here, since we don't use `h2` elsewhere that in `h4`, it would be shorter to directly print `hello` 4 times in `h4`. Likewise, for `h16`

```py
def h4():
    print("hello")
    print("hello")
    print("hello")
    print("hello")
def h16():
    h4()
    h4()
    h4()
    h4()
h16()
h16()
```

which are only 12 lines.

Now, here, number is 121. That is a specific number. Which is even the reason why I believe that this is the kind of expected solution: it is not easy to decide what intermediate function we need to create.

That would be an interesting problem per se: create a code, that optimize the number of lines needed, using this kind of subfunctions encapsulation.

But one combination that fit in 20 lines is

```py
def h3():
    print("hello")
    print("hello")
    print("hello")
def h7():
    h3()
    h3()
    print("hello")
def h15():
    h7()
    h7()
    print("hello")
def h60():
    h15()
    h15()
    h15()
    h15()
h60()
h60()
print("hello")
```

I know it is way less smart (and, even, "smart ass") than all the other solutions that were proposed. But I am really convinced that this is the kind of expected solution. It may seem too simple and naive. But it is not that an easy problem to decide which `h??` to write (well, it is not that hard if the constraint is just "fit in 20 lines". But I would have a harder time if the constraint was "use the smallest number of lines possible")

### Edit

I couldn't resist, so I wrote a code that optimize this

```py
def size(n, l):
    ml=max(k for k in l if k<=n)
    nm=n//ml
    r=n-nm*ml
    if r==0: 
        return nm
    else:
        return nm+size(r, l)

def sizefn(l):
    return sum(size(k, [x for x in l if x<k])+1 for k in l if k>1)

def totsize(n,l):
    return size(n, l) + sizefn(l)

rec=1000

def compute(l, k):
    global rec
    if k>120: return False
    sfn =sizefn(l) 
    if sfn+2>=rec:
        return False
    f = size(121, l)
    if sfn+f<rec:
        rec=sfn+f
        print(f'{sfn+f} ({sfn}+{f}) :', l)
    compute(l+[k], k+1)
    compute(l, k+1)
```

What it does is just try all possible combinations of intermediate functions. So, that is, theoretically 2¹²⁰ combinations (all intermediate function h? may exist or not), and count how many line of code that would be, and keep the best.
Except that I do it with Branch&Bound, allowing to avoid examination of whole subsets of the set of all combination.

Result is

```
121 (0+121) : [1]
64 (3+61) : [1, 2]
47 (6+41) : [1, 2, 3]
40 (9+31) : [1, 2, 3, 4]
37 (12+25) : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
36 (15+21) : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
35 (31+4) : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13, 39]
34 (28+6) : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 23]
33 (28+5) : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 30]
32 (28+4) : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 39]
31 (25+6) : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 23]
30 (25+5) : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 30]
29 (25+4) : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 13, 39]
28 (22+6) : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 24]
27 (22+5) : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 30]
26 (20+6) : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 23]
25 (19+6) : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 24]
24 (19+5) : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 30]
23 (17+6) : [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 24]
22 (16+6) : [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 24]
21 (16+5) : [1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 30]
20 (14+6) : [1, 2, 3, 6, 24]
19 (13+6) : [1, 2, 4, 8, 24]
18 (12+6) : [1, 2, 6, 24]
```

And it ends there.
Meaning that there is no better solution that the one with h2, h6, and h24 (h1 is just `print(hello)`)

For a total of 18 lines

Which gives

```py
def h2():
    print("hello")
    print("hello")
def h6():
    h2()
    h2()
    h2()
def h24():
    h6()
    h6()
    h6()
    h6()
h24()
h24()
h24()
h24()
h24()
print("hello")
```

Comment: I am convinced that this is what they are looking for as well.

Comment: @MitchellMatheny I've gone a bit further since you accepted the answer (thx, btw). So now I have (in the same spirit) a 18 lines solution. And a code to prove that there can't be a 17 lines solution (without tricks).

Answer (score 2):

Just using lists its pretty easy:

```
def myr(l=[lambda *a: 0] + 120*[lambda a, b: a(b)]):
    print("hello", end="")
    l.pop()(myr, l)

myr()
```

Comment: I love how your answer begins with "it's pretty easy" and then immediately resorts to black magic.

Comment: This is some `pythonic` anti-pattern: the list a default value for a function: https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html#anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Using lazy operators `and` or `or`, it is easy to fake a conditional in python:

```py
def print_hello(n):
    n > 0 and (print('hello') or print_hello(n - 1))

print_hello(3)
# hello
# hello
# hello

print_hello(121)
# ...
```

Comment: There are implicit conditions (without `if`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the short circuiting property of `and`.  Zero is False, every other number is True.  If the first part of the expression is false the second part isn't evaluated.

```
def print_hello(n=121):
   print('hello', end=' ')
   n and print_hello(n - 1)

print_hello()
```

Edit: I saw that you disqualified another answer because the function had a parameter, so here's a version that uses a global variable instead.  It also fixes an off-by-one problem in the original.

```
n = 121

def print_hello():
    global n
    print('hello', end=' ')
    n -= 1
    n and print_hello()

print_hello()
```

Comment: There are implicit conditions (without `if`).

Comment: @sergzach if you check the "constraints to the challenge" part of the question, I think you'll see this doesn't violate any of them.  The statement about "conditions" appears to be sloppy paraphrasing.

Comment: It's not very clear — you can easily replace any condition removing `if`, look: https://gist.github.com/sergzach/f613e0035cfe4c753546b210a4a950d0

Answer (score 2):

You could use a "higher-order function" such as `map`, `filter`, `max`, `min` or `sorted`, to apply a function repeatedly to a `range`.

```py
def print_hello_map(n):
    any(map(lambda _: print('hello'), range(n)))

def print_hello_filter(n):
    next(filter(lambda x: print('hello') or x + 1>= n, range(n)))

def print_hello_max(n):
    max(range(n), key=lambda x: bool(print('hello')))

def print_hello_sorted(n):
    sorted(range(n), key=lambda x: bool(print('hello')))
```

If you had allowed imports from the standard library, then there would have been many alternatives to `map` and `filter`, for instance `functools.reduce` and `itertools.repeat`, but also all functions from `itertools` that perform any kind of looping.

```py
from functools import reduce
def print_hello_reduce(n):
    reduce(lambda acc,x: print('hello'), range(n+1))

from itertools import repeat
def f(x):
    yield bool(print('hello'))
def print_hello_repeat(n):
    sum(repeat(f, n))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from sys import setrecursionlimit
setrecursionlimit(121)

def phello():
    print('hello', end='')
    phello()
  
try:
    phello()
except:
    print('done')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def print_hello():
    print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello'); print('hello');
```

Comment: Its not recursive though?

Comment: @MaximilianBallard **"but I can't seem to find a way to limit the recursive output without conditionals."** As I understand that's not a condition for the task.

Comment: @MaximilianBallard BTW, it's recursive. But the number of recursion calls is **zero.**

Answer (score 1):

```py
def print_hello(i):
   print('hello', end="")
   i -= 1
   a = 42 / i
   try:
       print_hello(i)
   except ZeroDivisionError:
       pass

print_hello(121)
```

The 42 could be anything really, just need to trigger the division by 0 error

Answer (score 1):

OK. Just another answer, just for fun.

```
def print_hello121():
    print(('\n'.join(['hello']*121)))
```

Here - we multiply the list, not the string.

Comment: "no new lines" so it should be `"".join(['hello']*121)`

Comment: The OP has edited the question to forbid the use of `'\n'`, although that's easy to sidestep with `'''<real line break>'''`.

Answer (score 1):

The idea.

```
def loop(x):
    try:
        next(x)
        print("hello", end="")
        loop(x)
    except StopaIteration:
        pass

def hello(n_repeat):
    loop(iter(range(n_repeat)))

...
hello(50)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_single_hello():
    print('hello')

def print_hello121():
    [print_single_hello()] * 121
```

This does not actually works correctly, but it can be an idea.

Comment: None of this ' * ' is allowed.